# How do I generate number for this kind of distribution?

Tags: fortran

I have to generate an integer number `z` which can take the values `+1` or `-1`: it represents the charge of muons. The problem is that positive muons are 1.3 times more abundant than the negative ones. How can I generate the charges with that distribution in Fortran?

Comment: Express as normalized probability: ~0.435 for negative, ~0.565 for positive; then generate random number: `charge = merge( +1, -1, rand()>0.435 )`. In average distribution should be 1:1.3.

Comment: Since `rand` is not a standard Fortran function you might want to revise @jcerar's suggestion to `charge = merge( +1, -1, random_number(harvest)>0.435 )` where `harvest` is either a real scalar or a real array of the size and shape you want.

Comment: Random_number is an intrinsic subroutine, so that doesn't quite work - you'll need to wrap it in a function or use two statements

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark with that code I have the error `Error: Function ‘random_number’ at (1) has no IMPLICIT type`

Comment: I have solved the problem using `call random_number(b) charge== merge( +1, -1, b>0.435 )`

Comment: As @IanBush has pointed out my previous comment was faulty, but OP seems to have been smart enough to fix it anyway.